# Regex to allow single hyphen and underscore but not at beginning or end of string

Tags: c#, regex

I have this Regex I modified to allow underscores, hyphen, letters and numbers.
I am trying to modify it further so that it has the following properties:

1. Allow only Numbers, Letters
2. Allow Underscore or Hyphen anywhere between the first and last character
3. **Cannot** start with ***underscore*** or ***hyphen*** *(only between first and last character).*

Here's what I have right now:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

Or this, which will simply ensure that the string does not start with a hyphen or underscore:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, was just reading on the Start With method but not sure I would add the end part, meaning where to check at the end. This works. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @UnaverageGuy For the sake of completeness I added a pattern wich only checks the start of the string, in case that's what you needed.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at over head with Regex. I actually need the front and end, so your solution is good. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])$
```

Either one of the three possibilities:

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]`