# Regex to allow single underscore and hyphen not in the beginning or end

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex to allow string with hyphen or underscore in between. But I am unable to make it work in to not allow at the beginning or end.

Here is my regex:

```regex
^(?!.*__.*)(?!.*--.*)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*$
```

This works except it allows `-` or `_` in the beginning or at the end. which should not have.

Additional requirements:

- `__` or `--` are not allowed anywhere in the string (but `_-` and `-_` are)
- apart from `_` and `-`, only alphanumeric characters are allowed

Comment: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824996/3832970).

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
^[^_-].*[^_-]$
```

There's just one pain-point: strings with 1 character length are not allowed at all. This might solve it:

```
^([^_-](.*[^_-])?)?$
```

And with the undocumented requirement of alphanumeric characters:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?)?$
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew addressed with 2nd version. Now you have to explain why it's TOTALLY wrong ;)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for the quick response 
^[^_-].*[^_-]$ --> I need to allow only _ and - in between alphanumeric characters.
sample:"fist_instance-s"  :-This should be allowed
"qq-ww_dq-"  :- not allowed "_qq-ww_dq" :- not allowed
"qq--d" :- not allowed

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can read text. The text didn't mention anything about this and a regex which doesn't work is not a contract

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I modified your last answer little bit. Now that solves my problem. Here is final regex that is exactly what I want:
^(?!.*__.*)(?!.*--.*)([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?)?$